# Use JavaFX on Android

Tags: java, android, javafx

According to https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/wiki/Home

I've installed JavaFX on my AndroidProject by including the external Jars "jfxrt.jar" and I would like to use the library in order to blend ImageView dynamically in my application.

But the main problem is that when I create an "Image" object from javaFx packages, it crashes when I give it the path to load the picture.

I'm currently using this syntax :

```
Image image = new Image(path)
```

But unfortunately this crash the application for me. Moreover, when after this I try to convert this Image into ImageView in order to display it and anim it in the android device, I have a conflict between android class "ImageView" and JavaFx class "ImageView".
So I have tried to call it as :

```
JavaFx.scene.image.ImageView imv = ..
```

But nothing to do..

Thank you in advance.

PS : I'm not sure of having well install javafx too.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaFX runtime for Android is a way to run pure JavaFX applications on the Android platform and it's not trivial. Here if I understand well, you only want to blend ImageViews ? There are other ways to do that with pure Android code.

Comment: Yes this is exactly it. I want to blend ImageViews but the very hard part is that they have to blend dynamically : I mean that 2 Imageviews are in translation, so I want to blend only the intersection part. Tell me if I'm not clear.

Comment: I don't know what you want to draw exactly, but you can blend bitmaps by drawing them both on a Canvas and optionnaly using PorterDuffXfermode on the Paint to apply transformations. If you just want two transparent images to overlap, you can simply translate two ImageViews using one of the Android animation systems.

Comment: In fact, I just want to "filter" (Multiply or Difference) the intersection of the 2 imageViews

Comment: Something like this? https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2380 I don't know if this is the best lib but you can do a search for a specific android lib. You don't have to use JavaFX for this.